# removing a style tag with javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a bookmarklet and am trying to remove a  tag that my js has inserted into the dom. It gets deleted, but the styles (that were overriden) do not update.

Is there anyway to trigger the browser to re-draw the page short of a refresh?

```
modal.addEventListener('click', destroy, false);
document.getElementById('brisk-modal').append(style);

function destroy(e) {
    document.getElementById('brisk-modal').remove();
}
```

Comment: Could you please add a working demo/[mre] ?

Answer (score 1):

use `disabled`

```
    document.getElementById("brisk-modal").disabled = true;
```

If you *then* want to remove the stylesheet

```
    document.getElementById("brisk-modal").parentNode.removeChild();
```

Works on style tags